# Failed to get month of current day after moment reformat in react with react calendar

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-calendar

So I am currently working on a project where I'm working with react calendar. When a date is clicked, all relevant appointments on that day should appear. In order to have the date align with the format of my database, I made use of moment js. This worked on all clicked values but not on the download of the current date. When I formatted the current date my code has broken with the following error:

> index.js:64 Uncaught Error: Failed to get month from date: 2022-06-25.

My code is as follows:

```
    const Calendar = (props) => {

//=============================================================================
// Variables
//=============================================================================
const [modal, setModal] = useState();
const timestamp = new Date();
const momentTimestamp = moment(timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
const [date, setDate] = useState(momentTimestamp);
const [formatDate, setFormatDate] = useState();
console.log(date);

const onDateChange = (newDate) => {
    setDate(newDate);
    setFormatDate(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    setRenderAppointents(true);
}

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
  date:'',
  userId:'',
});

const [userId, setUserId] = useState({
  activeUser: sessionStorage.getItem('activeUser'),
});


const [renderAppointents, setRenderAppointents] = useState();
const [appointmentItems, setAppointmentItems] = useState();


useEffect(()=>{


  console.log(formatDate);
  axios.post('http://localhost:80/project-api/readAppointments.php',formatDate )
  .then((res)=>{
    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
    let renderAppointents = data.map((item) =>  <AppointmentItems key={item.id} rerender={setRenderAppointents} uniqueId={item.id} vet={item.vet} client={item.client} time={item.time} date={item.date} room={item.room}  />);
    // console.log(data);
    setAppointmentItems(renderAppointents);
    setRenderAppointents(false);
    
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
  });

},[renderAppointents]);

return (
        <>
        {modal}
            <div className='row3'>
                <div className='calendar'>
                    <div className='block-heading' id='calendar-heading'> Calendar </div>
                    <CalendarContainer>
                 <Calendarcom calendarType='US' format="yyyy-mm-dd" className='react-calendar' 
                  onChange={onDateChange}           
                  value={date}  locale={"en-US"} />
                </CalendarContainer>

                </div>
                <div className='appointments'>
                    <div className='block-heading'> Appointments </div>
                    <button className='addBtn' id="btn" onClick={handleBooking}><div className='plus-icon' ><UilPlus/></div></button>
                    <table className='appointments-table'>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr className='row-heading'>
                            <th>Doctor</th>
                            <th>Patient</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Room</th>
                        </tr>
                        {appointmentItems}
                       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
          
        </>
     
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so ultimately, changing date was changing the date value that the calendar was reading, so the calendar was so longer able to read any dates. Therefore date and formaDate needed to be set separately and then formatDate was sent through to the php file.